# CodeIgniter -> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Estou a tentar solucionar este erro:

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: contratos/visualizar.php
>   Line Number: 37

**CÓDIGO:**

***contratos_model.php***

```
public function getById($id){

    $this->db->where('idContrato',$id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $consulta = $this->db->get('contrato')->result();

            foreach($consulta as &$valor){
                    $this->db->where('idCliente', $valor->idCliente);
                    $valor->curso = $this->db->get('cliente')->result();
            }

            return $consulta;

}
```

***contratos.php***

```
public function visualizar(){

    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vContrato')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para visualizar Contratos.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
    $this->data['result'] = $this->contratos_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['view'] = 'contratos/visualizar';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);

}
```

***visualizar.php***

```
<?
    print_r($result);
?>
```

***retorno do print_r do visualizador***

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [idContrato] => 3 [idCliente] => 3 [idCedente] => 2 [forma_de_pagamento] => 96 [nota_fiscal] => 94 [fechamento_de] => 1 [fechamento_a] => 1 [vencimento] => 1 [guias] => 0 [status] => 0 [curso] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [idCliente] => 3 [razaosocial] => PIXX CRIATIVA SOLUCOES LTDA [nomefantasia] => PIXX CRIATIVA SOLUCOES LTDA [cnpj] => 0655544801120 [ie] => 0 [im] => 0 [endereco] => [endereco_numero] => 0 [endereco_complemento] => [endereco_bairro] => [endereco_cep] => 0 [endereco_cidade] => [endereco_estado] => 12 [responsavel] => André Baill [responsavel_telefone_ddd] => 41 [responsavel_telefone] => 96479364 [responsavel_celular_ddd] => 0 [responsavel_celular] => 0 [email] => [data_ativo] => 1970-01-01 [codCedente] => 4 [fat_endereco] => [fat_endereco_numero] => 0 [fat_endereco_complemento] => [fat_endereco_bairro] => [fat_endereco_cep] => 0 [fat_endereco_cidade] => [fat_endereco_estado] => 12 [fat_responsavel] => [fat_telefone_ddd] => 0 [fat_telefone] => 0 [fat_celular_ddd] => 0 [fat_celular] => 0 [email_financeiro] => [vencimento] => 1 [nota] => 94 [fechamento_de] => 1 [fechamento_a] => 1 [guias] => 0 [valor_moto_normal] => 0 [valor_moto_metropolitano] => 0 [valor_moto_depois_18] => 0 [valor_moto_km] => 0 [valor_carro_normal] => 0 [valor_carro_metropolitano] => 0 [valor_carro_depois_18] => 0 [valor_carro_km] => 0 [valor_caminhao_normal] => 0 [valor_caminhao_metropolitano] => 0 [valor_caminhao_depois_18] => 0 [valor_caminhao_km] => 0 [status] => 0 ) ) ) )

Colei também no [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/uYwkfWDP)

Estou há dias tentando e não consigo imprimir os dados corretamente.

Tendo dar um `echo $result->campo`
Ai dá a mensagem acima.

Comment: Qual versão do CI é?

Comment: A versão é a versão 2.1.3

Comment: Poderia evidenciar a linha que ocorre o erro?

Comment: Linha 37: <td><?php echo $result->idContrato; ?></td>

Comment: ja tentou `echo $result[0]->campo`

Comment: Como eu recupero os dados que foram impressos no $result[cliente]?

Comment: Eu não entendi o pq daquele `foreach` no `getById()`, acho q da para simplificar um pouco.

Comment: A função final ficou desta forma: e funcionou.

Comment: Por que um foreach se você deu um limit 1?
Utiliza row() em vez de result();

Comment: @AndréBaill, aproveite e veja como o [site funciona](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) ele é diferente de um fórum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu objeto está dentro de um item do array, nesse caso você pode chamar ele diretamente pela chave.

Me parece que aqui é feita ta definição dele:

```
$this->data['result'] = this->contratos_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));
```

Na sua view chama dessa forma:

```
echo $result[0]->idContrato;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto:

print_r($result[0]->campo);

Tem outro objeto aninhado da mesma forma dentro do array cliente, para tanto acesse assim:

$result[0]->cliente[0]->campo

Comment: Retornou os dados da Array, normal... como o que eu colei acima.

Comment: Tentei usar o $result[0]->campo, e deu certo. Isto significa que todos os dados foram plotados num array... E pra recuperar, uso o ponto 0. Agradeço muito a atenção, fiquei o final de semana todo nisso e não conseguia arrumar... Obrigado Senhores.

Answer (score 0):

A versão final do getById ficou assim
   public function getById($id){

```
    $this->db->where('idContrato',$id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $consulta = $this->db->get('contrato')->result();


    foreach($consulta as &$valor){
        $this->db->where('idCliente', $valor->idCliente);
        $valor->cliente = $this->db->get('cliente')->result();

        $sql = "SELECT 
                    cf.*, 
                    f.idFuncionario, 
                    f.nome as nomeFuncionario 
                FROM 
                    contrato_funcionario as cf, 
                    funcionario as f 
                WHERE 
                    cf.idContrato = '".$valor->idContrato."'
                AND
                    cf.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario 
                GROUP BY 
                    f.idFuncionario";
        $valor->funcionarioLista = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    }


    return $consulta;

}
```

E funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Voce tambem pode usar na consulta:

```
$valor->cliente = $this->db->get('cliente')->row();
```

Aí pega o valor diretamente de uma linha apenas. O `->result();` invariavelmente gera um array indexado por valores numericos: [0], [1], etc.

Answer (score 0):

Você está retornando via array então neste caso é preciso que você uso o loop em array por exemplo usando o while ao invés do foreach, ou então retorne string para fazer o loop com o foreach.
ex: return $query->result();